# How to get ipv6 address on mac?

Tags: settings, ipv6

I see this in Settings, but not the ipv6 address.

Tried `ifconfig`

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether a0:78:17:80:b0:63 
    inet6 fe80::872:f16d:4262:fcbe%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xb 
    inet 192.168.0.74 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

But I was told, this is not real ipv6 address, but localhost or loopback: `fe80::872:f16d:4262:fcbe`

[image]

Comment: Not localhost or loopback, fe80:: is a 'Link Local Address' - addresses used for communication on your local LAN only. Looks like you don't have a device (e.g. your router) which is enabled to give you a global IPv6 address. Looks like a router problem.

Comment: Check with your ISP to see if they provide IPv6 service -- not all do. If they don't, and you really want to use IPv6, you can subscribe to a tunnel broker service, like [Hurricane Electric's](https://tunnelbroker.net).